# Nginx rewrite URL-Error

Tags: php, nginx

I have a Problem with my Nginx rewrite rule.

I have two Pages :

- First Page : category.php
- Second Page: subcategory.php

My Page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php 
                while($row = $smtp->fetch(PDO::ASSOC)){
                echo "li><a href='category.php? id='".$row['id']."'>'".$row['name']."'</a></li>";
                }

                ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
            while($row = $smtp->fetch(PDO::ASSOC)){
            echo "li><a href='subcategory.php?id='".$row['id']."'>'".$row['name']."'</a></li>";
            }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Problem is if I push a Link with `category.php?id=3`. I will get the same page with other values but the Links of `subcategory.php` looks different no `subcategory.php?id=1`

The looking like `category/subcategory/2`

The FireBug show right url: `subcategory.php?id=1`.

Why?

My rewrite rule :

```
rewrite '^/category.php/(.*)$' /subcategory.php?id=$1 last;
```

I need a Link like `subcategory/1` and not `category/subcategory/1`

Comment: Please edit your question to the human understandable level, it is difficult to understand it.

Comment: Sorry, it not very easy to explain. I have a Page with two Links on it, category.php and subcategory.php.

If i click on a category.php i get a new content from this category but if i want to load a subcategory a can not do it. Because my URL link look like category/subcategory/1.

I need a Link to load a subcategory. Right Link should look like subcategory/1 and not category/subcategory/1. The Link change himself if i click category.php at first.

Comment: According to your HTML, your URL looks like, baseurl/category.php and baseurl/subcategory.php, so how is baseurl/category/subcategory/1 is coming into scene?

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to understand :-). I do not know how to change from baseurl / category / subcategory / 1 to normal baseurl / subcategory.php

Comment: Can you show your nginx config, server block?

Comment: I have created this Rule

rewrite '^/category.php/(.*)$' /subcategory.php?id=$1 last;

Comment: That shouldn't affect baseurl/subcategory.php URL, please post some thing of your nginx config, there is some mysterious code

Comment: This is not nginx.conf. I remember me i have change the URL subcategory.php to category in 

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo '<li><a href="category/' . url($row['value']) . '">' . $row['value'] . '</a></li>';
     }

Comment: Bro I don't see any configuration file, can you edit your question along with that, I think link is not coming up in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few little issues here.

To answer your question, the first part is with the URLs in the href. You are using relative URLs and relative URLS get added to what the browser thinks is the current URL directory.

If you are at `http://yourdomain.com/category/[something]` then `href="subcategory.php?id..."` will send you to `http://yourdomain.com/category/subcategory.php?id...` - as the current ULR directory is `http://yourdomain.com/category/`

Even if the link is virtual (i.e. modified in .htacess) the browser doesn't know this and it's be browser that makes the links.

Your fix would be to use absolute urls `href="/subcategory.php?id..."` as this will send you to `http://yourdomain.com/subcategory.php?id...`

---

Another problem appears in your redirect.

You are looking to match:

```
http://yourdomain.com/category.php/[Something]
```

but what I presume you want to match is:

```
http://yourdomain.com/category/[something]
```

Hope that helps.